# how to use stored procedures in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

how to call stored procedure in EntityFramework?

```
 DB_9860_agentEntities db = new DB_9860_agentEntities();
 var outputparameter=new ObjectParameter("JobSearchAgentID",typeof(Int32));
 var outputparameter1=new ObjectParameter("ErrorCount",typeof(Int32));
 db.USP_BuildAgentPrifile_Submit_New(110, sess, resumeid, email, keyword, keywordopt, areaid, Convert.ToBoolean(resumesent), Convert.ToBoolean(active), country, zipcode, mile,  outputparameter, outputparameter1);
 ViewData["Jobsearchagentid"] = outputparameter.Value;
```

where outputparameter and outputparameter1 are output parameters.

Comment: Asp.NET MVC 2 is not a data access library, it knows nothing about databases. Perhaps you should amend your question to talk about whichever data access method you are using (ie Linq2Sql, EntityFramework).

Comment: Have you been through something like this? http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/wriju/Using-Stored-Procedure-in-ADONET-Entity-Framework-40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This topic provides two examples of
>   how to execute a parameterized stored
>   procedure with the Entity Framework .
>   The first example takes one input
>   parameter and returns a collection of
>   entity objects. The second example
>   takes one input parameter and one
>   output parameter and returns a value
>   in the output parameter. The examples
>   in this topic are based on the School
>   Model. To follow these examples, add
>   the School Model to your project and
>   configure your project to use the
>   Entity Framework . For more
>   information, see How to: Use the
>   Entity Data Model Wizard.

[How to: Execute a Query Using a Stored Procedure with In and Out Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896334.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Once you create your stored procedure, you need to add a function import within EF designer.  Follow these steps to do that:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx

Once that's done, you can call you stored procedure via your entity context instance.